# Defining a mongoose schema array of objects with ng-model

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, ng-tags-input

I'm a rookie at coding at the moment so please have patience if the material provided is not clear enough, I'll do my best.

Here's the problem

```
{ 
    email: 'asdf',
    password: 'asdf',
    userlists: { 
        list1: [ [Object], [Object], [Object] ] 
    } 
}
```

I want the terminal to send me back the array of objects as strings.

Im trying to use this schema,

**user.js**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
module.exports = mongoose.model('User', {
    email: String,
    password: String,
    userlists: {
        list1: {type:{ sublist1: String }},
        list2: {type:{ sublist2: String }}
    }
});
```

I've tried to set the `userlists` to an array of objects, this returns the same unwanted result, as well as empty arrays of the *list1* and *list2* if they are not filled in.

I want the user to use my following `$http.post` method together with `ng-model`, and I'm using `ngTagsInput` directive to let the user select premade "tags" when signing up.

**signup-controller.js**

```
 $scope.createUser = function(){
     console.log($scope.newUser);
     $http.post('api/user/signup', $scope.newUser)
     .success(function(response){

     })
     .error(function(error){
         console.log(error);
     })
 };
```

**signup.html**

```
<button ng-click="createUser()">Submit</button>

    <hr>
       <div>
        <tags-input ng-model="newUser.userlists.list1" display-property="sublist1">
          <auto-complete     source="tagsLoadedFromNgTagsInput($query)" 
                            min-length="1" 
                            load-on-focus="true"    
                            load-on-empty="true">
          </auto-complete>
        </tags-input>
       </div>
```

Here's the result I get from the server terminal when executed.
I want the objects inside the array to be displayed as strings, set by the input in signup.html above.

```
{ 
    email: 'asdf',
    password: 'asdf',
    userlists: { 
        list1: [ [Object], [Object], [Object] ] 
    } 
}
```

Here's the result when logging `db.users.find().pretty()` in the mongo shell:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("57efd2dbdcb311107b4830b2"),
    "email" : "asdf",
    "password" : "asdf",
    "userlists" : {
        "list1" : [
            {
                "sublist1" : "sometag1",
                "_id" : "57ed472b0c868aafab696b61"
            },
            {
                "sublist1" : "sometag2",
                "_id" : "57ed472b0c868aafab696b62"
            },
            {
                "sublist1" : "sometag3",
                "_id" : "57ed472b0c868aafab696b63"
            }
        ]
    },
    "__v" : 0
}
```

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `console.log` function wraps the objects before displaying it. For ensuring all data is displayed you must convert it to a string using `JSON.stringify` before calling the console.

```js
// Your object
var obj = {some: {nested: {object: {definition: 'hello world!'}}}};

// Print as a single line
console.log(JSON.stringify(obj));

// Print with 2 spaces identation
console.log(JSON.stringify(obj, null, 2));
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Works like a charm and makes total sense :)

Answer (score 0):

Use ng-repeat since list1 is an array .

```
 <tags-input ng-repeat="list in newUser.userlists.list1">
                <div>{{list.sublist1}}</div>
 </tags-input>
```

Comment: Im not sure i understand the answer but im not having trouble loading my tags in the frontend, im having problems getting the correct output in the serverside console.
Thanks for the answer tho i appreciate it!

Comment: use `console.log(Object.userlists.list1)`